# Vue: Can access nested object value in console, but not in template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm passing the following object as a prop to a Vue component:

```
formData: {
  buildings:{
    0:{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Example'
    }
  }
}
```

I want to bind the value of `id` to an `input`, as follows:

```
<input type="text" :value="formData.buildings[0].id">
```

Unfortunately, that code produces the error:

`Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`

However, when I try to access the property in the browser's console, I'm able to retrieve the value:

```
> $vm0.formData.buildings[0].id;
< 1
```

Is there anyway I can bind the nested value in the template? I'm guessing `v-for` would allow me to do so, but I'd prefer not to do that because:

- The `buildings` object will always contain only a single entry (there will never be a `formData.building[1]`). The nested `0` key is simply to keep structure of the `buildings` object consistent with other objects at the same level that can have multiple nested objects.
- The form in which I need this value contains `input` elements whose values will be bound to other objects in the `formData` object. For example, immediately following the input to which I need to bind the value of `formData.building[0].id` there could be an input to which I need to bind the value of `formData.renovations[0].id`. In light of that, it seems I would need nested elements with `v-for` to accomplish what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: buildings[0] not building[0]

Comment: Good catch--thanks! Unfortunately, same error. The code was correct, I just messed up the question.

Comment: are you getting data with ajax?

Comment: Not able to reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/8hLkxwy1/

Comment: Traxo: No, the data is passed as a prop to the parent of the child component, then the parent passes it along to the child.

Comment: @thanksd Thanks for that. I'm not sure what to make of it. I'm passing the object as a prop rather than defining it in the data function, so I don't know if that would have an impact.

Comment: Not able to reproduce in that case either: https://jsfiddle.net/wf8o2Lx5/ It must be that you are initially passing an object without a `buildings` property.

Comment: @thanksd Now that you mention it, that could be the issue. The data is passed as a prop to the parent, then I call a function in the `mounted` hook to add the `0` object (again, to keep the structure of the main formData object consistent). I imagine the template is compiling before the `0` object is added. So, the `building` object is there, but not the nested `0` object.